# system_time is more than current datetime

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am using [unitemporal](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal/managing#id_55585) ingestion in MarkLogic while loading a content using temporal api. I am seeing document metadata system time is 5:30 more of current dateTime. I have created an index and axes as suggested by MarkLogic .

Comment: Can you explain how you are inserting the document into MarkLogic?

Comment: i am using temporal:document-insert and passing options without system_start and system_end , as system_start and system_end will be handled automatically